# AngularFire / FireStore - getDownloadURL

Tags: firebase-storage, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire5

**What I'm using**

- AngularFire
- FireStore
- New AngularFire syntax for Firestore

**What I'm trying to do**

- get the download URL for each returned image

**Issue**

- I'm getting the download URL for the first image and applying it to a global variable.
- If four images are in storage, four are returned, but will all be the same image, opposed to four unique ones

**Question**

- I'm using the new AngularFire Firestore syntax to fetch the data
- How would I loop through each of the returned images and bind them to my HTML?

**Component TS**

```js
  getIssueImages() {

    this.albumsCollection = this.afs.collection<any>(/albums/${albumId}/images`);
    this.albums = this.albumsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {

        const data = a.payload.doc.data();

        const id = a.payload.doc.id;

        console.log(data);

        // Firebase Reference
        var storage = firebase.storage();

        // Get the image storage reference
        var image = data.image_thumbnail;

        //Create an image reference to the storage location
        var imagePathReference = storage.ref().child(image);

        // Get the download URL and set the local variable to the result (url)
        imagePathReference.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
          this.image_thumbnail = url;
        });

        return { id, ...data };

      });
    });

  }
```

**Component.HTML**

- As expected, this correctly returns the unique storage references of each image, but not the unique download URL references.

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let image of images | async">
    {{ image.image_thumbnail }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Component.HTML - Incorrect **

- So this one is trying to reference the firebase storage **downloadURL** that i'm trying to fetch from my function in my component.ts. As expected, I'm not looping through each one, an instead probably getting just the first item. As a result, all four images returned are the same.

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let image of images | async">
    {{ image_thumbnail }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**
Image update based on @James Daniels response.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem that you are facing is the async nature of getting the download URL. [You can solve that with an `Observable.fromPromise`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/frompromise.html).

```
getIssueImages() {

  this.albumsCollection = this.afs.collection<any>(/albums/${albumId}/images`);
  this.albums = this.albumsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
  return actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;

    // Firebase Reference
    var storage = firebase.storage();

    // Get the image storage reference
    var image = data.image_thumbnail;

    //Create an image reference to the storage location
    var imagePathReference = storage.ref().child(image);

    // Get the download URL and set the local variable to the result (url)
    var image_thumbnail = Observable.fromPromise(imagePathReference.getDownloadURL());

    return { id, image_thumbnail, ...data };

  });
});
```

}

Now `image_thumbnail` is async.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let image of images | async">
    {{ image.image_thumbnail | async }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi James! Thank you very much for the response. I included 'import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';' in my imports. Do I need to do anything else in regards to 'fromPromise'? The HTML shows a list of four urls (correct), but they are the reference URLs, not the download URLs. I also had to remove the 'asyn' pipe from the html. However, I've updated the question with an image if I do 'console.log('image_thumbnail') This might help? Anyway thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, by just changing image_thumbnail to a new variable name, such as 'newImageURL', it worked! - I think image_thumbnail was still referencing the original storage reference node name. Thank you James! :)